# select function using cucmber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to select secific element using cucumber. But it shows error.

Here my html

```
<div class="pagination">
    <ul>
        <li class="page active">
            <a href="/subscriptions">1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="page">
            <a rel="next" href="/subscriptions?page=2">2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="next_page">
            <a rel="next" href="/subscriptions?page=2">Next ›</a>
        </li>
        <li class="last next">
            <a href="/subscriptions?page=2">Last »</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

My step function is

```
But /^I click the pagination link$/ do
  within(".page a") do
    click_on("2")
  end
end
```

Here It shows error message as

```
But I click the pagination links              # features/step_definitions/subscription_steps.rb:206
  Unable to find link or button "Next >" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/subscription_steps.rb:207:in `/^I click the pagination links$/'
     features/subscriptions/test.feature:15:in `But I click the pagination links'
```

How may I fix this.

Note: I can't use `click_on(2)`. Because in my page have more 2's

Thanks for advise.

Comment: The exception and code do not seem to match. The exception is looking for "Next >" while the code is looking for "2". Are you sure you have pasted the right information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception is occurring because the code says to find a link with text "2" within a link that is within element with class "page".

Instead of having to deal with `within`, I think it is better to find the element directly. This allows you to find a link that matches both the css-selector and text:

```
find('.page a', :text => '2').click
```

or

```
first('.page a', :text => '2').click
```

Comment: Note that `find` may be better than `first`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And can you tell me where can I go and lean this kind of keywords like `click_on, find ,first, fill_in....`. better can you send me any link here

Comment: The gem's [github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara) and [API docs](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master), you are specifically looking for the [actions class](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions), are good places to start.